# How will detectors effect the inteference pattern in a double-slit experiment?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, double-slit-experiment, wave-particle-duality

We know that if you put a detector at the slits in the double-slit experiment, no matter before slits or behind slits, it'll destroys the interference pattern and resulting chunk pattern (particles only lands in two chunks). But since we know that even detectors are put after slits, it also destroys the pattern, it makes me wonder how far away a detector can be to still effects the pattern? Like how distance between slits and detectors effect the pattern at the screen. Cause if you didn't detect the particle right at the slit, you wouldn't be that confident which slit it goes through. Yet experiment shows that detectors after slit do effect the pattern, then is there a relationship between distance and how much it effects the pattern? Or the detector must be right after the slits?

Comment: If you are talking about photon (particles) the answer is easy. A photon is detected when it’s absorbed. Place something in the way of the photons trajectory and it will not reach the screen. In other words it will not contribute to an interference pattern. If you place something just before the screen it will create a shadow right there on the screen.

Comment: @BillAlsept Then how about for electrons?

Comment: When electrons are accelerated they emit billions of photons in every direction. Again it is photons ultimately responsible for the pattern on the screen.

Comment: @BillAlsept Your last comment does not make sense in the context of mainstream physics.

Comment: @BillAlsept Richard Beth in 1935 detected photons without absorbing them. See https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://users.df.uba.ar/schmiegelow/materias/FT2_2010_1C/extra/PhysRev.50.115.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwj515z_3P7pAhWPCuwKHXipCI4QFjAPegQICRAB&usg=AOvVaw2eQ4J5emVmdDnXXkZP9FP1

Comment: @my2cts Beth detected that it is possible to rotate the photons fields and he measured the recoil from these rotations.

Comment: @my2cts Anyway, your comment was the starting point of a new question https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/559146/mechanical-detection-and-measurement-of-the-angular-momentum-of-light-make-the

Comment: @my2cts I totally agree with that article. Maybe absorbed was too strong of a word because photons can be  scattered. My point is that anything placed in the path of the photon alters the pattern on the screen.